# Usage of auto for global constants

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

Suppose I have something like this:

```
namespace {
  const unsigned MY_UINT = 100u;
  const float MY_FLOAT = 0.f;
  const char* MY_STRING = "Hello World";
}
```

Do I get expected behavior by using `auto` for these? I presume this is an improvement, but I'm not sure about this in practice.

```
namespace {
  auto MY_UINT = 100u;
  auto MY_FLOAT = 0.f;
  auto MY_STRING = "Hello World";
}
```

Are the two code examples semantically the same? Will these be `const` automatically? If not, should I specify `auto const`?

Comment: You can use `auto` for declaring `static` class data members as well.

Comment: `auto` is for typing not scoping - you still need to mention your use scope with it e.g. `const auto`, `extern auto`, `static auto`

Comment: `const char* MY_STRING = "Hello World";` should probably be `const char* const MY_STRING = "Hello World";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto`'s deduction rules are equivalent to by-value template argument deduction. Creating an object by value entails stripping references and top-level cv-qualifiers from the initializer. Your two examples are not equivalent. In particular, the primitive `100u` is of type `unsigned int`, so that's what it is deduced as. Likewise, `0.f` is of type `float`.

Adding `const` only makes sense if the variable *itself* will not be modified. If you want to make constants in your program, using `constexpr` might be better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must manually specify it `const`.

No, it is not a good practice. You generally shouldn't overuse `auto`. That keyword can be helpful if name of type is very long but `typedef` is often better solution. `Auto` obscures code. Moreover, this facilitates errors. Sometimes the type that deduce the compiler may not be the same as what you mean.
You can use `auto` if you want but better don't do it without a reason.

Comment: Thanks for your general advice on `auto`, but [I like Herb Sutter's opinion better](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/).

Comment: Catch the another link. http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#auto This is the basis for my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same.

When you type:

```
auto var = 123u;
```

It is the same as:

```
unsigned var = 123u;
```

To achive

```
const unsigned var = 123u;
```

You should write

```
const auto var = 123u;
```

Do not expect from auto too much. Some kind of magic guesses.